# handling events with UITableView 

Tags: ios, uitableview, event-handling

This is what I am trying to do...but not sure how to do :

I have a tableview consisting of multiple rows in multiple sections. When I scroll the table going from 1 section to another, I want to do some other action - I want to have an action handler for this. But, I am not sure how to do it.

Cany anyone please help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: first you have implement that how to make a tabview with your number of required tab.like 3,4,5.

Comment: @scorpio : I already have the table. I was thinking what to do about the action handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tableview delegate as the controller and implement this delegate function

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This function will get called before a cell is going to be displayed. You can use the indexpath to check if it is going to be first item in a section.

Hope this helps.